# How does IKE with PSK really work and how secure is it?

Tags: ipsec, ike

There is many articles that describe some exploitation techniques on a VPN with `IPSec - IKE-PSK`.

However, I can't understand how the flaws may exist. Thus, I have some question relating to that:

1) Why, in *Aggressive mode*, the authentication hash is transmitted **as response** to the initial packet of the VPN client that wants to establish an `IPSec` Tunnel ? As a result of this, anyone on the Internet may get an authentication hash from any VPN servers exposed on the Internet. A more secure way may be that the client must send first the authentication hash right?

2) What is **exactly** that authentication hash? Is it a message hashed with the `PSK`?

3) When we say that the hash is encrypted in *Main Mode*, what is the encryption key used?

4) Is it possible to simply perform a relay attack (like `SMB` relay for example), when a client tries to connect to the VPN server? I don't see any reason that you can't do that, as **identity peer is not checked with IKE-PSK**. This solution is easier than cracking the hash...but no article talks about it.

Thanks for your answers